# What is "OspReceiver" all about?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Using Dalvic Debug Monitor I have noticed that slight pauses in my game coincide with the appearance of the following messages:

```
03-23 19:02:21.234: D/SamsungAccount(5691): [OspReceiver.java/Lines:44] OnReceive begin
03-23 19:02:21.234: D/SamsungAccount(5691): [OspReceiver.java/Lines:112] OnReceive end
```

What do they mean? And could I stop them happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do they mean?

They mean that a piece of software written by Samsung -- presumably a `BroadcastReceiver` named `OpsReceiver` -- spent 0 milliseconds doing some work and decided to log that fact to LogCat.

> And could I stop them happening?

You as a programmer? Probably not.

You as a user? Possibly -- you would have to ask Samsung.